# How do you send data from client to server on Netcode for GameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm currently trying to create a login system for an MMO social platform game similar to horizon worlds or vr chat. This is the first time I have ever done something like this as I have only developed single player games prior to this. So far I have managed to create an authentication API that would send a string token to the client and to the database upon successful authentication of the user credentials. My plan was after the client receives the token, the client sends the token to the game server so that they can finally connect to it but I don't really know how to do that. The networking solution I used for the client and game server is the Netcode for GameObjects and while it's been a great tool I don't have a good understanding of how it works.

I feel like the solution is really simple but considering my zero experience in back end development and the fact that I am only getting by because of tutorials on youtube I can't really see it.

One thing I have been trying is using TCP or UDP sockets to send the token and then after the server verifies it, the client can enter the server. But it honestly feels redundant, like I'm already using NGO so shouldn't I use that all the way? Idk, I really want to just solely use NGOs if possible.

Comment: Depends. I wouldn't say it is redundant if it fulfills your use case. If you want to negotiate the authentication before even connecting to NGO as a client I would say its totally valid to do so. Otherwise you could also let any client connect, from the server side initiate the auth process by calling a certain RPC - if the client does then answer wrong or not at all you can kick it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NGO has a connection approval step that can be enabled.
This allows the server to accept or reject connections on a per connection basis.

Be aware that the data used in the payload is not encrypted or authenticated.
You should take steps to ensure that the data sent is secured.

[Connection Approval Reference](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/connection-approval/)

Comment: That's actually a convenient feature I didn't see youtube multiplayer tutorials use. Thank you